# Emberjs syncing with persistent layer

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a real time emberjs app. I'm trying to implement a real time notification system, where any updates on one client will be propagated over all the other clients. Hence all the changes happen in real time over all the browsers.

I have Labels extending DS.Model objects. Every time one client creates a new record, the other clients run App.Label.find() which updates the record array correctly. Now the problem is when a client deletes a record and commits the store, App.Label.find() will no remove the record on the other clients. So my question is:

Is there a way you can update your local records from a persistent layer, which will remove all the deleted records?

Comment: You could try using Web sockets to remove the entities that have been deleted on the server: http://livsey.org/blog/2013/02/10/integrating-pusher-with-ember/

Answer (score 0):

I got it done by checking for .isDeleted

```
{{unless "model.isDeleted"}}
show only not deleted models
{{/unless}}
```